# Double Linked List in Julia

Tags: linked-list, julia

I'm new to Julia language and I wanted to improve my understanding by implementing a double linked list.
Unfortunately it seems that there is no good existing library for this purpose.

The only good one is the single linked list ([here](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/list.jl)).
There is one implementation of a double linked list ([here](https://github.com/adolgert/Lists.jl/blob/master/src/list.jl)). But this is 2 years old and I'm not sure if it is outdated or not. And it does not allow a real empty list. It is just a single element with a default value.

At the moment I would be able to implement the common stuff like push!, pop!, that's not the problem.
But I'm struggling with implementing a double linked list that could be empty.
My current approach uses Nullable for a optional value of the reference and value.

```
type ListNode{T}
    prev::Nullable{ListNode{T}}
    next::Nullable{ListNode{T}}
    value::Nullable{T}
    ListNode(v) = (x=new(); x.prev=Nullable{x}; x.next=Nullable{x}; x.value=Nullable(v); x)
    ListNode(p, n, v) = new(p, n, v)
end

type List{T}
    node::Nullable(ListNode{T})
    List() = (start=new(Nullable(ListNode{T}())); node=start; start)
    List(v) = (start=new(Nullable(ListNode{T}(v))); node=start; start)
end
```

But it seems like this is pretty ugly and inconvenient to work with.
My second approach would be to introduce a boolean variable (inside List{T}) which stores if a list is empty or not. Checking this boolean would me allow to simply handle push! and pop! to empty lists.

I tried to google  a good solution but I didn't found one.
Can anyone give me a "julia style" solution for the double linked list?

Thanks,
felix

Comment: I think you may not have fully grasped how `Nullable` works. A `Nullable` object is not "null" by default. It just means it can assume a 'null' state. You initialising your node with itself seems counterintuitive; I'm assuming you just wanted to initialise with "null", right?

Comment: FWIW, I actually just updated Lists.jl yesterday. [You can see the fork I made for the PR here](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/Lists.jl). The original Lists.jl is far over-typed and repeats a lot, so I would suggest taking a look at this for a more Julian style.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I didn't really test the code above.
It is more about the principle of using Nullable here.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks, this looks good. You always have one node with a default value (0 when List{Int}) at beginning, but you start your list at List.next, that is smart.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a library containing various data structures, [DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl) Some initial notes regarding the question. As of this writing, *type* is decrepitated. Instead, mutable struct should be used, for Julia 1.0 and beyond. *Nullable* is also decrepitated, and a Union of Nothing and the type in question can be used instead.

There exist a package called DataStructures.jl that provides what you need.
You can find a DoubleLinked list containing the functionality you need here: 
[mutable_list](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/mutable_list.jl)

Code snippets from the link above, defining a DoubleLinked list in Julia >= v 1.1:

```
mutable struct ListNode{T}
    data::T
    prev::ListNode{T}
    next::ListNode{T}
    function ListNode{T}() where T
        node = new{T}()
        node.next = node
        node.prev = node
        return node
    end
    function ListNode{T}(data) where T
        node = new{T}(data)
        return node
    end
end

mutable struct MutableLinkedList{T}
    len::Int
    node::ListNode{T}
    function MutableLinkedList{T}() where T
        l = new{T}()
        l.len = 0
        l.node = ListNode{T}()
        l.node.next = l.node
        l.node.prev = l.node
        return l
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [DataStructures package](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl), [Chris Rackauckas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544203/chris-rackauckas) [LinkedLists.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/LinkedLists.jl) is a good resource.

The [source code](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/LinkedLists.jl/blob/master/src/list.jl) is quite readable and you can always ask questions.